# want to remove space above figure

Tags: beamer, spacing, floats

I am using this code

```
\RequirePackage[demo]{graphicx}  % to deal with non-available graphics files
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title }

\begin{columns}
\column{0.5\textwidth}
\vspace{-1cm}
  \begin{figure}[htb]
  \includegraphics [height=2in,width=2in]{fig1.pdf}
  \end{figure}
\pause
\begin{itemize}
  \item text \pause \vspace{0.3cm}
  \item text \pause
  \end{itemize}
\column{0.5\textwidth}
\vspace{-1cm}
\begin{figure}[htb]
  \includegraphics [height=2in,width=2in]{fig2.pdf}
  \end{figure}
\pause
\begin{itemize}
\item text \pause \vspace{0.3cm}
\item text
\end{itemize}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The second figure is not in alignment with the first figure on the top margin. In fact the second figure is eating some space from the slide header. How do I fix this. Please help

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I've taken the liberty of adding a few instructions at the beginning and end of your code to convert it into a compilable LaTeX document. Note that because we don't have access to the files `fig1.pdf` and `fig2.pdf`, it's rather difficult to provide an exact diagnosis. Are the figures both square in shape, and/or is one noticeably taller than the other? Please advise.

Comment: This MWE compiles for me with no alignment problems. Something specific to your source data (and specifically your graphics or maybe overall document styles you've tweaked) must be causing this. You might try working up from the example in your question as it currently stands and adding the real pieces until it fails, then tell us about what those pieces look like.

Comment: What's the `figure` environment for? You don't need it and it's possibly a cause for bad behavior.